# Read Text from Image (OCR) in C# with IronOCR Tesseract

Tags: c#, ocr, tesseract

According this [Link](https://ironsoftware.com/csharp/ocr/tutorials/how-to-read-text-from-an-image-in-csharp-net) I installed the IronOcr package and I try the follow code.

```
using IronOcr;
var Result = new IronTesseract().Read(path);
string currentSubText = Result.Text;
textBox1.Text += currentSubText + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
```

I tested it with six pictures:

Picture [image: 1]

Picture [image: 2]

Picture [image: 3]

Picture [image: 4]

I could just upload four pictures.

Actually it looks good. There are just a few mistakes with some special German language characters (äöü)

Result 1:[image: 5]

I google and found it is possible to use a language package in OCR. I try it with the follow code.

```
var Ocr = new IronTesseract();

//Ocr.Language = OcrLanguage.German;
Ocr.Language = OcrLanguage.GermanBest;

using (var Input = new OcrInput(path))
{
    var Result = Ocr.Read(Input);
    string currentSubText = Result.Text;
    textBox1.Text += currentSubText + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

Unfortunately the result is very, very bad.

Result 2:[image: 6]

Can someone help me here?

Thanks and best regards

Comment: How bad is "very very bad" and what does the picture look like?

Comment: @Fildor, Sorry I had problems to upload the pictures. Now I could upload the example and results pictures.  Instead of words there are just letters

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using the built in inversion color filter?

All OCR tends to work best for me with black text on white.  I use this code based on code found in the IronOCR documentation:

https://ironsoftware.com/csharp/ocr/examples/ocr-image-filters-for-net-tesseract/

Simplified source code:

```
using IronOcr;
 
var Ocr = new IronTesseract();
Ocr.Language = OcrLanguage.GermanBest;
using (var Input = new OcrInput(@"image.png"))
{
    
    //Input.EnhanceResolution(300);
    Input.Invert();
    
    
   
    /*
    // Optional: Export modified images so you can view them.
    foreach(var page in  Input.Pages){
          page.SaveAsImage("filtered.bmp")
    }
    */
   
 
    var Result = Ocr.Read(Input);
    Console.WriteLine(Result.Text);
}
```

MSDN style docs:
https://ironsoftware.com/csharp/ocr/object-reference/api/IronOcr.OcrInput.html#IronOcr_OcrInput_Invert_System_Boolean_

Comment: Also try: `Ocr.Language = OcrLanguage.German;` or `Ocr.Language = OcrLanguage.GermanFast;` or `Ocr.Language = OcrLanguage.LatinAlphabet`